# Make command freezes building ICU with mingw

Tags: makefile, windows-7-x64, icu, mingw32

This is what I’m doing for linking statically.

```
$ ./runConfigureICU MinGW --enable-debug --disable-release --prefix=/mingw/dist --enable-static --disable-shared
```

It ends up OK, i think.

```
ICU for C/C++ 52.1 is ready to be built.
=== Important Notes: ===
Data Packaging: static
 This means: ICU data will be stored in a static library.
 To locate data: ICU will use the linked data library. If linked with the stub library located in stubdata/, the application can use udata_setCommonData() or set a data path to override.
Building ICU: Use a GNU make such as make to build ICU.
checking the version of "make"... 3.81 (we wanted at least 3.80)
ok
If the result of the above commands looks okay to you, go to the directory
source in the ICU distribution to build ICU. Please remember that ICU needs
GNU make to build properly...
bash-3.1$
```

Then I run make command:

```
 $ make && make install
```

And after some work, it hangs at:

```
make[0]: Making `all' in `data'
```

When I check the process with  process explorer it shows no CPU activity whatsoever and the state is:  wait:UserRequest

Somebody went through this? Any help welcome.

**UPDATE**: result after addding -d option as suggested.

```
make[0]: Making `all' in `data'
GNU Make 3.81
Copyright (C) 2006  Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.
There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A
PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
This program built for i686-pc-msys
Reading makefiles...
Reading makefile `Makefile'...
Reading makefile `../icudefs.mk' (search path) (no ~ expansion)...
Reading makefile `../config/mh-mingw' (search path) (no ~ expansion)...
Reading makefile `../icudefs.local' (search path) (don't care) (no ~ expansion)...
```

Using: Window 7 x64, mingw 4.8.1-4,

Comment: Looks to me like some command that make is invoking is asking for user input, but the output is redirected somewhere else so you don't see the prompt.  You need to run with `-d` or similar to see what commands make is invoking.

Comment: I updated the result with your suggestion. It does not have any meaning to me.

Answer (score 0):

I have used the patches from http://sourceforge.net/projects/msys2/files/REPOS/MSYS2/Sources/mingw-w64-icu-52.1-1.src.tar.gz/download Thanks to the developers of msys2. After patching the source it compiles fine... Please let me know if you have any additional queries.I have use the following patches:

```
patch -p1 -i icu4c-4_9_1-mingw-w64-mkdir-compatibility.patch
patch -p1 -i icu-config.patch
patch -p1 -i icu-pkgconfig.patch
```

I have gone through PKGBUILD and applied patches as mentioned in that file

Comment: It contains several files with patch extension, but I do not know how to apply them. Is there any readme file or some guidance?

Comment: I tried "icu4c-52_1-src.zip" with the patches metioned to build a x64 version, but still cannot go over this issue.

Answer (score 0):

For me, changing the file *source/config/mh-mingw64* from

```
# Current full path directory.
#CURR_FULL_DIR=$(shell pwd -W)#M# for MSYS
CURR_FULL_DIR?=$(subst \,/,$(shell cmd /c cd))#M# for Cygwin shell
# Current full path directory for use in source code in a -D compiler option.
#CURR_SRCCODE_FULL_DIR=$(subst /,\\\\,$(shell pwd -W))#M# for MSYS
CURR_SRCCODE_FULL_DIR=$(subst \,/,$(shell cmd /c cd))#M# for Cygwin shell
```

to

```
# Current full path directory.
CURR_FULL_DIR=$(shell pwd -W)#M# for MSYS
#CURR_FULL_DIR?=$(subst \,/,$(shell cmd /c cd))#M# for Cygwin shell
# Current full path directory for use in source code in a -D compiler option.
CURR_SRCCODE_FULL_DIR=$(subst /,\\\\,$(shell pwd -W))#M# for MSYS
#CURR_SRCCODE_FULL_DIR=$(subst \,/,$(shell cmd /c cd))#M# for Cygwin shell
```

did the trick with MSYS.